# How to get two!!! specific value of array In JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

I am trying to do a system that i can get back two specific value
for instance: j=8 and j = 5 but it doesn't want to please help me! Thanks

```
for (var val in resultats[j].Nom + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1) {
    $('<option />', {
        value: resultats[5].Nom & resultats[8].Nom , 
        text: resultats[5].Nom & resultats[8].Nom
    }).appendTo(dropDownList);
    j++;
}
```

Comment: You will have to explain what you're trying to do more clearly.

Comment: I am trying to get the value on the array at different position like tab[i] where i = 5 and i = 8 only!!!! index 5 and 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to only use `resultats[5]` and `resultats[8]` in your loop? Try this:

```
var keys = [5,8];
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
{
  resultat = resultats[keys[i]];
  $('<option />',{
    value: resultat.Nom,
    text: resultat.Nom
  }).appendTo(dropDownList);
}
```

Comment: yes this Was I looking for!  resultats[5] and resultats[8] :)

Comment: thanks!!!! it works! :) I close my question.